# How to use Vue.compile in custom render function?

Tags: vuejs3

I wrote a quite simple component like this:

```
import { compile } from 'vue';

let f1 = compile('<p>{{abc}}</p>');

let f2 = function (_ctx, _cache) {
  let c = compile('<p>{{ abc }}</p>');
  return c(_ctx, _cache);
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      abc: 'Hello ABC'
    }
  },
  render: f1
}
```

If I set render to f1, everything will be OK. But if I set render to f2, it will give me an error: Property undefined was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. But still, the abc can be rendered correctly.

I want to use f2 so that the template can be dynamic, how can I remove this warning? Or are there better ways to dynamic render template?

I have tried to solved search the answer for quite a long time, there is little answer about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy component that can render a dynamic template (with interpolations) which you can use as inspiration:

```js
import { h } from 'vue';

const defineDescriptor = (src, dest, name) =>
{
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
  if (!dest.hasOwnProperty(name))
  {
    const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, name);
    Object.defineProperty(dest, name, descriptor);
  }
};

const merge = (objs) =>
{
  const res = {};
  objs.forEach((obj) =>
  {
    obj &&
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach((name) =>
      defineDescriptor(obj, res, name)
    );
  });
  return res;
};

const buildFromProps = (obj, props) =>
{
  const res = {};
  props.forEach((prop) => defineDescriptor(obj, res, prop));
  return res;
};

export default
{
  name: 'RuntimeTemplate',
  props:
    {
      template: String,
      parent: Object,
      templateProps:
      {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({}),
      },
    },
  render()
  {
    if (this.template)
    {
      const parent = this.parent || this.$parent;
      const {
        $data: parentData = {},
        $props: parentProps = {},
        $options: parentOptions = {},
      } = parent;
      const {
        components: parentComponents = {},
        computed: parentComputed = {},
        methods: parentMethods = {},
      } = parentOptions;
      const {
        $data = {},
        $props = {},
        $options: { methods = {}, computed = {}, components = {} } = {},
      } = this;
      const passthrough = {
        $data: {},
        $props: {},
        $options: {},
        components: {},
        computed: {},
        methods: {},
      };

      // build new objects by removing keys if already exists (e.g. created by mixins)
      Object.keys(parentData).forEach((e) =>
      {
        if (typeof $data[e] === 'undefined')
        {
          passthrough.$data[e] = parentData[e];
        }
      });
      Object.keys(parentProps).forEach((e) =>
      {
        if (typeof $props[e] === 'undefined')
        {
          passthrough.$props[e] = parentProps[e];
        }
      });
      Object.keys(parentMethods).forEach((e) =>
      {
        if (typeof methods[e] === 'undefined')
        {
          passthrough.methods[e] = parentMethods[e];
        }
      });
      Object.keys(parentComputed).forEach((e) =>
      {
        if (typeof computed[e] === 'undefined')
        {
          passthrough.computed[e] = parentComputed[e];
        }
      });
      Object.keys(parentComponents).forEach((e) =>
      {
        if (typeof components[e] === 'undefined')
        {
          passthrough.components[e] = parentComponents[e];
        }
      });

      const methodKeys = Object.keys(passthrough.methods || {});
      const dataKeys = Object.keys(passthrough.$data || {});
      const propKeys = Object.keys(passthrough.$props || {});
      const templatePropKeys = Object.keys(this.templateProps);
      const allKeys = dataKeys.concat(propKeys).concat(methodKeys).concat(templatePropKeys);
      const methodsFromProps = buildFromProps(parent, methodKeys);
      const finalProps = merge([
        passthrough.$data,
        passthrough.$props,
        methodsFromProps,
        this.templateProps,
      ]);

      const provide = this.$parent.$.provides ? this.$parent.$.provides : {}; // Avoids Vue warning

      const template = this.template || '<div></div>';
      const shadowDOM = document.createElement('div');
      shadowDOM.innerHTML = template;
      // attach event handlers
      if (this.templateProps && typeof this.templateProps.events === 'object')
      {
        const vueComponents = shadowDOM.querySelectorAll('variable,lookup,reference,choice,cost');
        const eventHandlers = Object.entries(this.templateProps.events);
        for (const comp of vueComponents)
        {
          eventHandlers.forEach(([eventName, eventHandler]) =>
          {
            if (typeof eventHandler === 'function')
            {
              comp.setAttribute('event-handler-func-' + eventName.replace(/^on/, ''), eventHandler.name.replace('bound ', ''));
            }
          });
        }
      }
      // a subarticle inside an Option which is not currently selected should not increment the numbering
      const unselected = passthrough.$props.unselected;
      const optional = this.templateProps ? this.templateProps.optional : false;
      const subarticles = shadowDOM.querySelectorAll('subarticle');
      for (const sub of subarticles)
      {
        // a subarticle inside an Option should not show a floating toolbar
        if (optional)
        {
          sub.setAttribute('optional', 'true');
        }
        else
        {
          sub.setAttribute('optional', '');
        }
        if (unselected)
        {
          sub.setAttribute('unselected', 'true');
        }
        else
        {
          sub.setAttribute('unselected', '');
        }
      }
      const dynamic = {
        name: 'DynamicRuntimeTemplate',
        template: shadowDOM.innerHTML.replaceAll('event-handler-func-', '@'),
        props: allKeys,
        computed: passthrough.computed,
        components: passthrough.components,
        provide,
      };
      // debugger;

      return h(dynamic, { ...finalProps });
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Your implement looks like similar as vue3-runtime-template. I used this before. But when I try to add a v-model, it just can't work correctly. I solved this with this code: render() { let c = compile(this.template); return h({ ...this.$options, render: c }); } It looks working now. I think the problem is caused by the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the following code.

```
import { compile } from 'vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      abc: 'Hello ABC'
    }
  },
  render() {
    let c = compile('<p>{{ abc }}</p>');
    return h({ ...this.$options, render: c });
  }
}
```

I think it is a scope problem. Don't know what happen in the h function.